# Recursive search and move of a filesystem

Tags: command-line, bash, files, filesystem

I have a filesystem that I would like to organise alphabetically. It's large and to do it manually would take a lifetime.

What I would like to know is whether it would be possible to write something in the terminal that will create folders A-Z and then have the terminal search the entire filesystem and move all subfolders into their respective letters folder.

I would also like the search to organise based upon the file extension found inside the subfolder.

for example find and move all subfolders beginning with the letter A containing file extension .doc to folderA.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that you want only the direct first-level subdirectories of your working directory sorted into alphabetical folders? I am not sure what you mean with "recursive" here.

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: So where is the recursiveness then? Do you want to sort all subdirectories of each original directory into alphabetical folders? So would `./apples/bananas/cherries` become `./A/apples/bananas/cherries` or `./A/apples/B/bananas/C/cherries`? And what about files - sort them too, or only directories?

Comment: by recursive I mean that it will go through the whole working folder. the second example would be best and just the directories not the files inside

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `find` command below to recursively (depth-first) move all folders into a folder named after the first letter of their file name, creating it if it does not exist yet, starting from your current working directory:

```
find . -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -execdir bash -c 'l=./$(basename "{}" | head -c1) ; test -d "${l^^}" || mkdir "${l^^}" ; mv "{}" "${l^^}/"' \;
```

**Explanation:**

- `find . -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -execdir <COMMAND> \;`
  recursively searches your current directory (`.`), depth-first (`-depth`), for all directories (`-type d`), excluding your current directory itself (`-mindepth 1`).
  Then it `cd`s into each found folder's parent directory and executes `<COMMAND>` from there, replacing every occurrence of `{}` with the relative found directory name (`-execdir`).
- `bash -c '<COMMAND>'`
  starts a Bash subshell and lets it interpret and execute the string `<COMMAND>`. We need this because we're going to use shell features like variables, pipes, command substitution, etc, which can't be done directly by `find -execdir`.
- `l=./$(basename "{}" | head -c1)`
  stores the first letter of the found directory name (remember that `{}` gets substituted with the search result) in the shell variable `$l`.
- `test -d "${l^^}" || mkdir "${l^^}"`
  checks whether a directory exists and creates it if not. The name of the directory (`"${l^^}"`) is the content of the variable `$l` (the first letter of the found directory name) converted to upper case.
- `mv "{}" "${l^^}/"`
  moves the found directory (remember again that `{}` gets substituted) into the directory named after its first letter converted to upper case (`"${l^^}/", which we prepared earlier).

**Example run:**

```
$ tree -F
.
├── apple/
│   ├── hamster/
│   ├── horse/
│   ├── snake/
│   │   ├── blue
│   │   ├── green
│   │   ├── grey
│   │   └── red
│   └── spider/
├── apricot/
├── banana/
├── cherry/
│   ├── pink
│   ├── purple
│   └── yellow
└── coconut/

9 directories, 7 files
$ find . -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -execdir bash -c 'l=./$(basename "{}" | head -c1) ; test -d "${l^^}" || mkdir "${l^^}" ; mv "{}" "${l^^}/"' \;
$ tree -F
.
├── A/
│   ├── apple/
│   │   ├── H/
│   │   │   ├── hamster/
│   │   │   └── horse/
│   │   └── S/
│   │       ├── snake/
│   │       │   ├── blue
│   │       │   ├── green
│   │       │   ├── grey
│   │       │   └── red
│   │       └── spider/
│   └── apricot/
├── B/
│   └── banana/
└── C/
    ├── cherry/
    │   ├── pink
    │   ├── purple
    │   └── yellow
    └── coconut/

14 directories, 7 files
```

**Edit:**

If you want it non-recursively, i.e. operating only on the direct first-level subdirectories of your current working directory, simply add the `-maxdepth 1` option to the `find` command. You can omit the `-depth` option then though:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir bash -c 'l=./$(basename "{}" | head -c1) ; test -d "${l^^}" || mkdir "${l^^}" ; mv "{}" "${l^^}/"' \;
```

**Edit 2:**

It is possible to only perform the move if the directory to move contains files matching a specific criterion (here: contain a file with file name ending in `.jpg` anywhere, including subdirectories), but it adds another `find` command and an `if` clause:

```
find . -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir bash -c 'if find "{}" -type f -iname '*.jpg' | grep -q '.' ; then l=./$(basename "{}" | head -c1) ; test -d "${l^^}" || mkdir "${l^^}" ; mv "{}" "${l^^}/" ; fi' \;
```

**Explanation (after edit 2):**

- `if <CONDITION> ; then <COMMANDS> ; fi`
  Checks the exit code of the command `<CONDITION>` and only runs the `<COMMANDS>` between `then` and `fi` if the condition was fulfilled (exit code 0). `<COMMANDS>` is the same as in the previous version.
- `find "{}" -type f -iname '*.jpg' | grep -q '.'`
  Searches inside the directory found by the outer `find` command (remember once again that `{}` gets substituted) for files (`-type f`) with a name that ends with `.jpg`, case-insensitively (`-iname '*.jpg'`).
  The `grep -q '.'` simply checks whether the `find` produces any output on STDOUT (means that files were found) and returns an exit code of 0 then, 1 if no files were found.

**Example run (after edit 2):**

```
$ tree -F
.
├── apple/
│   ├── hamster/
│   ├── horse/
│   ├── snake/
│   │   ├── blue
│   │   ├── green
│   │   ├── grey
│   │   └── red
│   └── spider/
├── apricot/
├── banana/
│   └── black.jpg
├── cherry/
│   ├── pink
│   ├── purple
│   └── yellow
└── coconut/

9 directories, 8 files

$ find . -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir bash -c 'if find "{}" -type f -iname '*.jpg' | grep -q '.' ; then l=./$(basename "{}" | head -c1) ; test -d "${l^^}" || mkdir "${l^^}" ; mv "{}" "${l^^}/" ; fi' \;
$ tree -F
.
├── A/
│   └── apple/
│       ├── hamster/
│       ├── horse/
│       │   └── white.jpg
│       ├── snake/
│       │   ├── blue
│       │   ├── green
│       │   ├── grey
│       │   └── red
│       └── spider/
├── apricot/
├── B/
│   └── banana/
│       └── black.jpg
├── cherry/
│   ├── pink
│   ├── purple
│   └── yellow
└── coconut/

11 directories, 9 files
```

Comment: Ok it looks good, except I think I've mislead you, I would actually prefer not to sort the subdirectories, just all of the primary directories in the file tree.

Comment: @Johnny Well, you said "recursive" and when I gave you the two apple/banana/cherry examples, you picked the second one. Anyway, to disable the recursiveness, just add `-maxdepth 1` as argument to the `find` command, e.g. like this (shortened): `find . -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir <COMMAND> \;`

Comment: Also don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the grey round check button on its left if it fully solves your question. Otherwise feel free to ask back if something is still unclear or suboptimal. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok I also want to tell the find command to only move folders with a certain filetype inside, so that it will only move the folders with .jpg files in for example

Comment: @Johnny It has been suggested in chat that you keep changing the specs of what you're asking for.  Please state ***all*** the things you need the commands to do, so that we don't have to constantly revise scripts just to adjust to a new specification.

Comment: Sorry for causing problems although I did state that in the initial post

Comment: @Johnny You're right, sorry, it was there already, just written a bit confusingly IMHO. However, I edited my answer again so that it should hopefully suit your needs now.

Comment: OK I tried running this commmand in a small folder as a test and received this error message > find: paths must precede expression: *filename*.jpg
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec|time] [path...] [expression]  *filename*.jpg is a loose .jpg file within the working directory

Comment: @Johnny That error doesn't make sense, I can't reproduce your problem. What was the exact command that you pasted? It would also be helpful if you could add the output of `tree -F` of that small folder to your question, so that I know what exact directory structure you're operating it on.

Comment: OK I paste this find . -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir bash -c 'if find "{}" -type f -iname '*.jpg' | grep -q '.' ; then l=./$(basename {} | head -c1) ; test -d "${l^^}" || mkdir "${l^^}" ; mv "{}" "${l^^}/" ; fi' \;  and I get this

Comment: basename: extra operand ‘Of’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
mv: './AAA01 [2016]' and './AAA01 [2016]' are the same file
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: command substitution: line 1: `basename ./DMary 128 | head -c1)'
basename: extra operand ‘-’

Comment: Try 'basename --help' for more information.
mv: './Dave [04]' and './Dave [04]' are the same file
basename: extra operand ‘[HGH15]’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
mv: './Alm [HGH15]' and './Alm [HGH15]' are the same file.

Comment: I suspect it crashed on a name containing spaces because I missed a quote. Edited all commands in my answer, try again please.